# Difference in behavior between .first() and .nth(0) when resetting index after grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

I've encountered unexpected behaviour when using pandas' groupby function followed by .first() and .nth(0). The behaviour of the resulting DataFrame's index seems to differ between the two methods after resetting the index.

When using .first(), I get the expected 'postdistrict' column:

`df_entry = df_deliveroo.groupby('postdistrict')['FIRST_ORDER_imputed'].first().reset_index(drop=False)`

Output:

```
print(df_entry.head())
  postdistrict FIRST_ORDER_imputed
0         AB10          2015-09-04
1         AB11          2015-09-01
2         AB12          2019-07-11
3         AB15          2019-10-04
4         AB16          2018-11-29
```

However, when I try to achieve the same result with .nth(0), the 'postdistrict' values are replaced by default integer indices:

`df_entry = df_deliveroo.groupby('postdistrict')['FIRST_ORDER_imputed'].nth(0).reset_index(drop=False)`

Output:

```
print(df_entry.head())
   index FIRST_ORDER_imputed
0      1          2013-01-31
1      0          2013-02-01
2      3          2013-02-04
3      4          2013-03-01
4      5          2013-03-13
```

What could be causing this difference in behavior, and how can I ensure that the .nth(0) method retains the 'postdistrict' values in the resulting DataFrame's index?